# Condition of continuity

Tags: functional-analysis

In paper  [Tempered distributions and the Fourier transform](https://math.mit.edu/~rbm/iml/Chapter1.pdf), on page 16,  we can find following quote:

> If we fix $\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ this defines a continuous linear linear map:
>   $$ T_{\phi}:\;\mathcal{S}\ni\psi\mapsto\int\phi(x)\psi(x)dx. $$
>   Continuity becomes the condition:
>   $$ \exists \; k, C_k \;\text{s.t.}\;|T_{\phi}(\psi)| \le C_k||\psi||_k \; \forall \;\psi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n). $$

Note that norms on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are defined as

> $$||\phi||_k = \max_{|\alpha|+|\beta|\le k} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} |x^\alpha D^\beta \phi(x)|.$$

where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N}^{n}_{0}$.

My question are,

1. Why does *Continuity becomes the condition*?
2. What is the definition of *Continuity* the author refers to?

Comment: The space of Schwarz functions is what is known as a Frechet space. It does not have a norm, but instead a family of seminorms which you may use to define a topology in which the space is complete. Continuity "becomes" that condition, because continuity of linear functionals means the preimage of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ is an open set in the Frechet space topology on $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Comment: In my opinion, the wikipedia page does a good job of explaining this topology:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my question in [Kôsaku Yosida, Functional analysis](https://the-eye.eu/public/WorldTracker.org/Mathematics/Algebra%20%26%20Trigonometry/Functional%20Analysis%206th%20ed%20-%20K.%20Yoshida%20%28Springer%2C%201980%29%20WW.pdf).

[image]